# Class method which returns an array of itself. How to annotate and inherit?

Tags: javascript, typescript

The example below is a raw representation of what’s going on in real code (I'm not working with HTML or front-end. The code below is a dummy code. Sorry if it does not make any sense from front-end perspective)

TL, DR

I’m struggling to specify a return type of method which will return an array of class instances of the class **from which this method was called**.

Back to dummy code:

**PageElement.ts**

```
class PageElement {
    public element: HTMLElement
    constructor(
        public elementSelector: string,
        public elementName: string,
        public description: string,
        
    ) {
        this.element = document.getElementById(this.elementSelector)!;
        
    }
 
    getAll() {
        let foundElements = document.querySelectorAll(this.elementSelector);
        let returnElements = [];
        let constructor = this.constructor as any;
        foundElements.forEach(
            element => returnElements.push(
                new constructor(
                    element.attributes['id'].value,
                    this.elementName + (returnElements.length + 1),
                    this.description
                )
            )
        )
 
        return returnElements;
    }
}
```

Let’s say this class has lots of child classes, e.g.:

```
class InputElement extends PageElement {
    constructor(
        elementSelector: string, 
        elementName: string, 
        description: string) {
        super(elementSelector, 
            elementName, 
            description
        )
    }
 
    exclusiveInputMethod() {
        // this method exist only on InputElement 
    }
}
```

There are two core issues I would like to fix

```
getAll() {
        let constructor = this.constructor as any;
}
```

The logic above works fine in JS like `new this.constructor(...)` .
However, TS does not allow to do this with error: `This expression is not constructable. Type 'Function' has no construct signatures.ts(2351)`

So I need to do `let constructor = this.constructor as any;`. But this kills IntelliSense and all type safety.

Of course, you could say: “Just return an array of `PageElement`, duh”:

```
getAll() {
        let foundElements = document.querySelectorAll(this.elementSelector);
        let returnElements = [];
        foundElements.forEach(
            element => returnElements.push(
                new PageElement(
                    element.attributes['id'].value,
                    this.elementName + (returnElements.length + 1),
                    this.description
                )
            )
        )
 
        return returnElements;
    }
```

*But here is where the problem with inheritance comes up:*

```
class InputElement extends PageElement {
    constructor(
        elementSelector: string, 
        elementName: string, 
        description: string) {
        super(elementSelector, 
            elementName, 
            description
        )
    }
 
    exclusiveInputMethod() {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

In case `getAll` will return an array of `PageElement` I will not be able to access the `exclusiveInputMethod`. Because when I’ll call `InputElement.findAll()` it will return `PageElement[]` instead of `InputElement[]`.

I’ll summarize my questions:

What is the proper equivalent of `new this.constructor` for TS so it knows, that I’m creating an instance of this particular class?

The second question is (well, it’s actually the same as first):
How can I annotate (or make TS to infer return type properly) method `getAll()` so it always knows that the return type is an array of the class instance from which this method was called?

Answer (score 4):

Specify `this[]` as the return type of your method:

```
class PageElement {
  getAll(): this[]  {}
}

class InputElement extends PageElement {
  aSpecificInputElementMethod() {}
}

const inputElement = new InputElement();
const inputElements = inputElement.getAll();

inputElements[0].aSpecificInputElementMethod(); // valid;
```

See it in action on [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKYHMCmBRESC2SB2AXaA3gLABQ00yuAgiCABQCUAXNLgBYCWEA2gLrnEy5aACckuAK4js0buy68A3KXIBfUupKlQkGAElsABwm40mHPiQAPXDgAmMeMjNY8hFdDABlQ0mAcAMw5gA2NTdFdcAFlxNgB7O0ZCTU1tOOwIfA4jExcLaABeaGwkAHdoUNyIi0ZlEmB0zOhssLy8GCKWqvM8ADpKGnoGOtIu8J7cHgAGXl7vX38gkJzxyJj2BNroAHpt6AA3MBAOO0UgA).

Answer (score 2):

Not actually an ideal way, but you can specify the return type as the type argument

```
getAll<T>(): T[]
```

And then call like

```
getAll<InputElement>
```

The downsides are:

- You need to specify type argument every time you call `getAll`
- Type argument should always be a valid type
- You can pass **any** type of an argument

So basically there is not a lot of type safety because it’s up to you to keep the type argument valid every time you call `getAll`.
This will probably cause issues if you are working in a team.

Maybe someone can suggest a way on how to restrict generic type to be an instance of this particular type.

Comment: Yeah... this approach has some potential human-related issues. I don't know the way how to validate what caller is passing in `<...>`. But thanks anyway